# What are the purpose of the following ESXi SSH keys? ssh_host_rsa_key, ssh_host_rsa_key.pub?

Tags: ssh, vmware

New to VMware ESXi 6.5, I use ssh-kgen generated a SSH Key pairs and upload to the ESXi host. The public key of the key pairs is in the following EXSi host file.
`/etc/ssh/keys-root/authorized_keys`

However, I also noticed the following two SSH Key files and couldn't find much information about what are they used for?

`/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key`

`/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`

They are different than the key pairs I generated in my local Macbook. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Those files are the ESXi's host key pair. SSH host keys are used to authenticate computers. See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/160833/why-does-a-ssh-server-need-a-host-key-pair) for more information.

If you delete these files, you won't be able to connect to your ESXi host via SSH anymore.

Comment: The last paragraph may be dependent on the actual case - many machines use ECDSA host key these days, and it's when deleting the RSA key pair doesn't affect much.

Comment: @iBug You're right. At least in ESXi 5 it was the case that deleting the host keys prevented you to connect via SSH (as per https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2041660)